# passing the output of first prosy service to second proxy service in WSO2 integration studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

In WSO2 integration studio I have created two proxy services. The URL of second proxy service is dependent on the output of first proxy service. How can I set a variable in the the URL part of second proxy service so that I can pass the output of first proxy service to that variable field in second proxy URL.

ex- 1st proxy URL - http://host:port/something/upload
    output - XYZ

```
2nd proxy URL - http://host:port/somethingElse/XYZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the output of the 1st proxy and enrich it to a property. After that, you can use that property to construct the URL of the 2nd proxy.

Sample examples are given in this blog for constructing a dynamic URL.
https://medium.com/@Jenananthan/wso2-esb-construct-dynamic-urls-67fad2f6d34c